# Windows 8.1: HDMI switches of after 20 min, where to prevent?

Tags: windows-8.1, hdmi, sleep

All,

I've got an HDMI cable connected to my amplifier for sound/video. After updating Windows 8 to 8.1 my audio system automatically switches to my PC speakers. When touching my PC again it comes alive and switches back to my HDMI output.

Where can I disable this HDMI power saving or sleep mode?
** Drivers fully up-to-date
** Switched off USB sleep
** Power management settings besides screen to black disabled

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got Windows power set to turn off your screen after a defined amount of time? Do you notice your problems start at this time? Try setting to turn off the screen to "never" and see what happens...